# Cat Sub-Q Ringer's Solution: Not DPHV Free?

Tags: cats, safety, medicines

I received a donation or 4 bags of Hospira Brand Ringer's Solution (1000 ml each) and they say that they are not DPHV-free. My cat is in Stage 3 kidney disease. Is it too dangerous to trust this type of solution for even a few weeks? He must have 150 ml per day.

The bags have already reached their expiration dates. Two were "expired" on Jan 1, 2018, and the other two were expired 2 weeks ago on Feb 1, 2018. The entire plastic quality is not clear like with some other brands bags, but the color is the same for the entire bag, not just where the solution is stored. Solution looks "clear" and not cloudy or darker than the plastic. Probably not as dark as the plastic.

I was told when given these bags that the bags should be used within the next 4 weeks.

What do I do? There is a scarcity of Ringer's Solution/IV bags right now due to the hurricane in Puerto Rico that disabled the facilities that provide most of these products to the USA. Each bag is going for $16 each in my area.

Comment: Related question [How long do subcutaneous fluids (lactated ringers) keep?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/how-long-do-subcutaneous-fluids-lactated-ringers-keep) does not address DPHV-free but does address expired date

Comment: Also related: [Can I use expired subcutaneous fluids on my cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7898/can-i-use-expired-subcutaneous-fluids-lactated-ringers-on-my-cat?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Additionally, I can't find anything on google about what the concern with DPHV is in solution. Do you know what that stands for?

Comment: @Zaralynda I think they mean DEHP, which is part of some plastics used in the bags.  Search for dehp free iv bags

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, these IV products are safe to use. Assuming they were safe 2 months ago and have been well taken care of since, they are ok now.

See these two related questions for more detail

- [How long do subcutaneous fluids (lactated ringers) keep?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/how-long-do-subcutaneous-fluids-lactated-ringers-keep)
- [Can I use expired subcutaneous fluids (lactated ringers) on my cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7898/can-i-use-expired-subcutaneous-fluids-lactated-ringers-on-my-cat)

I believe you mean DEHP, this is part of the formula used in some plastics.  There are a some concerns about it long term use.  There are a few companies making bags without DEHP.

> Several investigators have reported the finding of polycystic kidney disease (PKD) at autopsy in patients who had undergone long-term hemodialysis for renal failure due to causes other than PKD. We initiated studies to determine whether the drugs or chemicals to which patients on dialysis are exposed could be responsible for these cystic changes. Adult rats were tube fed chemical residues from an artificial kidney or phthalate esters [di(2-ethylhexyl) phthalate, DEHP], which are a main component of these plastic kidneys or a control solution. Rats receiving DEHP or residues showed a significantly higher incidence of focal cysts when compared to controls. Rats receiving DEHP developed a significant decrease in kidney function as demonstrated by creatinine clearance, and these animals had the highest tissue levels of measureable DEHP. We postulate that patients receiving long-term dialysis may acquire PKD secondary to their exposure to chemicals leached from artificial kidneys. [source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3361614)

Optimally you would prefer non-DEHP bags that have not reached their expiration date. But assuming you are not using in the long term and the treatment is medically necessary the minor risks is probably tolerable. You will of course need to make your own final decision.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, James.  Some days I am not sure if it will all end this week, and others I think there could be months.  The main concern is hydration.  Kidney diet foods are also becoming less appetizing, though they were initially eaten well and with a fair amount of relish.  We're at Stage 3 but the vet a month later said that our cat's numbers were unexpectedly getting much worse.  Other than Ringer's solution daily (150 ml), we are now seeing lack of appetite.  We are giving oral Ranitidine syrup 2x's daily for heartburn to stop vomiting & help appetite.  Thanks Again!