# While setting up lactated ringers bag I accidentally poked it with needle causing small leak, can I still use?

Tags: dogs

While setting up lactated ringers bag I accidentally poked it with needle causing small leak, if I tape the hole can I still use it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, new bag and new needle. I played it safe and did not use. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

No, you have compromised the contents.  Tape is not going to make a seal that will keep the contents sterile.

I am assuming the needle was new and sterile.

I am assuming a brand new bag, that was just removed from it's outer container.

In this case and if an emergency I might use it for the one IV/Sub Q dose that I was trying to deliver when I accidentally poked the bag.  But I would throw it out and get new supplies for the next treatment.

If either the Bag or Needle were not brand new at the time of the accident, I would not even consider it for emergency use. Excepting life or death, which this would not be if there is time to look online for an answer.

Related [How long do subcutaneous fluids (lactated ringers) keep?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/how-long-do-subcutaneous-fluids-lactated-ringers-keep)