# Is it okay to heat a lactated ringer's bag using a sous vide cooker?

Tags: cats, safety, temperature

I have been told that cats like it better if their subcutaneous fluids are administered from a bag that has been warmed a little bit.  I like this idea, but I don't trust my arbitrary means of heating the water to a good temperature.  I happen to have a sous vide cooker which is really good at heating water to a specific temperature.

Could I use this to heat the fluid bag to the desired temperature (submerging it in a water bath)? I reuse each bag about 10 times.

As a side question, what's the ideal temperature? (I would assume it's the same as the cat's natural body temperature, but I don't want to make assumptions.)

Comment: Are you using the bag once and disposing of it? Or are you using the bag multiple times?

Comment: I'm using it multiple times (about 10)

Answer (score 4):

No,

In your case you are using the bag multiple times.  Every time you submerge the bag in water you are exposing it to germs.  Additionally you would be warming the bag to the perfect temperature for more germs to grow.

Single use bags are available; the lactated ringer's bag is inside of another bag that protects it from germs, you could warm it before taking it out of the protective bag.  In hospitals there is a special machine that warms the fluids.  If that machine is not available running warm water over the bag is next best choice.

Related posts

- [How long do subcutaneous fluids (lactated ringers) keep?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/6220/13)
- [While setting up lactated ringers bag I accidentally poked it with needle causing small leak, can I still use?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/16097/13)
- [Cat Sub-Q Ringer's Solution: Not DPHV Free?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/19755/13)

Answer (score -2):

The bag is air tight and sealed.I do not see any reason why it can’t be warmed and keep the business end of it out of the water.It is a sterile solution so it would remain sterile if warmed.

Comment: But if the bag is used many times, this means the fluid will be refilled or the fluid would be warmed and cooled many times. With each temperature change chemicals inside would be destroyed or with refilling the "sealed" part is not fullfilled anymore...