# Is an open bag of lactated ringers solution still safe to use?

Tags: cats

I started my cat on IV subq fluids for kidney issues. I only gave it to him a few times then stopped (for various reasons). I want to start giving it to him again but don't know if I can use the already open bag or if I need to buy a new one. It is lactated ringer's, with a 3/2024 exp. date on the bag, last used 2 weeks ago, opened/started a few days prior to that.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Maybe of interest for you: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/how-long-do-subcutaneous-fluids-lactated-ringers-keep

Comment: Bit of a 'cop out' but worth checking with your vet

Comment: It's probably safe, depending on how it was handled and stored, but remember that you're going to be injecting it directly into your cat. If random chances go against you, worst case is you spend a boatload of money at the vet and despite all that you kill your cat. Slightly better case is you spend a boatload of money at the vet and you save the cat. Or you could toss the bag and buy a new one for a few bucks and avoid the whole mess.